# Format currency in google sheet to center values but all aligned on the decimal

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

If you pick the one of the stock currency formats in google sheets, you will get this after you pick alignment = centered:

```
|     $1.23     |
|    $123.45    |
|   $1,234.56   |
```

I'm looking for a way to align on the decimal, in centered mode like this:

```
|       $1.23   |
|     $123.45   |
|   $1,234.56   |
```

or this

```
|   $    1.23   |
|   $  123.45   |
|   $1,234.56   |
```

I tried playing around with some formats mentioned [on google's documentation for formatting](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/56470?visit_id=638425979312835605-1179429057&p=drive_custom_numbers&rd=1#zippy=%2Ccustom-number-formatting),  and this almost worked: `"$"??,??0.00`, based on the idea that if I first pad to a certain number of digits, then the centering will give desired effect. But this shows the comma even for numbers smaller than 1000:

```
|   $  ,  1.23  |
|   $  ,123.45  |
|   $ 1,234.56  |
```

Ideas how to make that comma visible only when needed, or maybe there is another format string altogether?

Comment: Could you get a bit more specific with what you're doing, and what you're trying to do? When I put `=GOOGLEFINANCE("MSFT")` into a cell, it's aligned as I expect, but I am guessing this is not what you're trying to do. You can use this [Sample Spreadsheet Maker](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform) to help share the challenge without revealing any personal google drive files.

Comment: You might try this.  Maybe not perfect, but close... `_($* #,##0.00_);_($* (#,##0.00);_($* "-"??_);_(@_)`

Comment: Thanks @Codedabbler I had to fix the expression to work, I included it in the solutions I discuss in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some solutions I found. My needs are satisfied by Solution 2.

### Various solutions

The solutions refer to this image:

[image]

***Solution 1***: it's a hack!

```
[>=1000]$?????,0.00;[<1000]$?????0.00
```

which hides the comma for numbers <1000. This syntax is not documented in the link above, I found it via a blog post that chatgpt recommended.

Example: Column D in the image.

I consider this a hack because it is not generic: it is hard to extend to case where some numbers are negative, or numbers >= 1M, or both. This is because google sheets requires that there be only 4 "fields", which are separate by semicolons, so in the above technically the second field is for negative numbers, but produces almost perfectly desired effect. Also alignment is not perfect of you look carefully

***Solution 2***: if you can live with spaces instead of commas

A better solution replaces the comma by a space, in which case the ranges are not necessary and we can adhere to the correct syntax documented for format strings:

```
_-$? ??? ??0.00;-$? ??? ??0.00
```

Example: Column E in the image

This is easy to remember because it is the exact same format for pos and neg numbers except for the contents between quotes, and is easily extended to larger ranges of numbers.

***Solution 3***:

I found a pretty crazy format string in an account sheet that I happened upon by coincidence:

```
_-[$$-1009]* #,##0.00_-;\-[$$-1009]* #,##0.00_-
```

Example: Column F in the image

However this is not easy to remember, nor would it be easy to modify, so while impressive, I probably won't use it. Also, it does more than what I need, eg the left alignment of -$ and padding with spaces.

***Solution 4***: fixed the suggestion by @Codedabbler

```
_ $* _(#,##0.00_);_ $* (#,##0.00)
```

Example: Column H in the image

This is simpler than Solution 3 and sufficient (I don't need locale), and somewhat tricky to remember due to the parentheses and to the padding necessary before the dollar sign (otherwise dollar sign too close to the edge). This is my second choice out of all.

Column I has additional settings if you want to show 0 as "-" with proper alignment. This is even harder to remember unless you use these sheets every day.

***Solution 5***: app script

This can also be done with scripting (not surprisingly):

```
var formats = [
  "$??? ??? ??0.00", // Format for values < 1000
  "$??? ???\",\"??0.00", // Format for values between 1000 and 999999
  "$???,???,??0.00"  // Format for values >= 1000000
];

function alignDollarsOnDecimalPoint() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange("G2:G11");
  var values = range.getValues();

  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    var value = values[i][0];
    var format = getFormatForValue(value, formats);
    var cell = range.getCell(i + 1, 1);
    cell.setNumberFormat(format);
  }
}

// Helper function to compute the format string based on the value
function getFormatForValue(value, formats) {
  var absValue = Math.abs(value);
  var logValue = absValue === 0 ? 0 : Math.log10(absValue);
  var formatIndex = Math.floor(logValue / 3);
  // Cap formatIndex at 2 for values >= 1000000:
  formatIndex = formatIndex > 2 ? 2 : formatIndex; 
  
  // Determine format adjustment for positive values
  var format = formats[formatIndex];
  if (value >= 0) {
    // Add space equivalent to "-" for positive numbers
    format = "_-" + format; // Prepending a space to align with negative numbers if needed
  }
  return format;
}
```

Example: Column G in the image

Although this more powerful, it has a couple of disadvantages over using Solution 2:

- requires some experience with programming; although chatgpt is good at producing app script code, you still have to know basic programming
- Must be triggered, cannot be used as a formula: this means you have to run the function by clicking a button when you want to "cleanup" your alignments; clearly easy to forget and automating this (eg so it runs whenever you change a number in the range) will be non-trivial to setup, and potentially slow

### Non-solutions

- Condition formatting (as in Format -> Conditional Formatting): not an option as cell format cannot be a format string, just colors and text style.
- Formula: there are no formulas for programmatically setting the format of numbers, formula are only for cell values not cell formats.
- Format `_-$??????,0.00; -$??????,0.00` from my Question because Google Sheets shows too many commas